# Conexão CLI do Jenkins Negada

Tags: java, jenkins

Ao executar

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -remoting -s http://maquina:9090 get-job TAL -auth user:1457c2
```

Estou a receber conexão negada por algum motivo. Jenkins versão 2.89. Alguma ideia do porque do erro? Pilha de erro:

> ```
> java.io.EOFException
>   at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
>   at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:609)
>   at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
>   at hudson.cli.CLI.connectViaCliPort(CLI.java:254)
>   at hudson.cli.CLI.<init>(CLI.java:137)
>   at hudson.cli.CLIConnectionFactory.connect(CLIConnectionFactory.java:82)
>   at hudson.cli.CLI._main(CLI.java:615)
>   at hudson.cli.CLI.main(CLI.java:426)
>   Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://maquina:9090/cli?remoting=true
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1839)
>       at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1440)
>       at hudson.cli.FullDuplexHttpStream.<init>(FullDuplexHttpStream.java:101)
>       at hudson.cli.CLI.connectViaHttp(CLI.java:163)
>       at hudson.cli.CLI.<init>(CLI.java:141)
>       ... 3 more
> ```

Comment: Tenta executar esse passo a passo no Gerenciador do Jenkins (de outro tópico): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42783458/server-returned-http-response-code-403-error-installing-jenkins-plugin

Comment: Você está recebendo um HTTP 403.. Você tem permissão pra acessar a outra máquina?

Comment: Resolvi a questão de permissão com a linha de comando: java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -remoting -s http://maquina:9080 get-job %Versao%_%Pacote% -auth user:1457c278-557 . No entanto, estou a tomar o ERROR: No such job '3.15.4.1_Intranet'